# Recover Deleted table in microsoft sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server

I deleted table in Microsoft SQL Server 2012.
Now I need data from deleted table.
How to recover deleted table without using tool.

Comment: You can't, it's gone unless you have a backup to restore.

Comment: So you have a backup of your database and you want to restore a single table from it? Then restore the whole database into a new (temp-)db on the same server. Then you can use `SELECT * INTO TableName
FROM backup_database.TableName`. If you don't have a backup... sorry

Answer (score 1):

> recover the deleted table  with the help of Transaction Log and
>   LSNs.For more details please visit the below detailed link

[Recover Deleted row Or Deleted table from SQL server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3160/recover-deleted-sql-server-data-and-tables-with-the-help-of-transaction-log-and-lsns/)